# Rails: why is calling `valid?` only validate some of associated record not all associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model `Order` which is like

```
# app/models/order.rb
class Order< ApplicationRecord
   has_one :detail
   has_one :extra
..
end
```

I have two `orders`

```
order1 = Order.first
order1.detail #<OrderDetail:0x00 name: "abc", remark: 'test1'>
order1.extra  #<OrderExtra:0x00 email: nil, recipent: nil>

order2 = Order.second
order1.detail #<OrderDetail:0x00 name: "abc", remark: 'test1'>
order1.extra  #<OrderExtra:0x00 email: nil, recipent: "xyz">
```

When I call `order1.valid?` or `order1.save!` it will not check `OrderExtra` validation and returns true. But when I call `order2.valid?` or `order2.save!` it checks `OrderExtra` validation.

```
order1.save! # true
order2.save! # ActiveRecord Invalid OrderExtra
```

I want to know how rails checks if they want to check associated validation when call `save!` and the reason behind that.

Please let me know if any additional requirement needed on this.

Answer (score 2):

use the `validates_associated` for enforcing associated model validations

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  belongs_to :library

  validates_associated :pages, :library
end
```

This validation will not fail if the association hasn’t been assigned. If you want to ensure that the association is both present and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use `validates_presence_of`.

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :books
 validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Comment: Thanks that helps me.But I am more interested in knowing the reason how rails decide to validate the associated record? In my case it validate one while discard check for another order.